# Hibernate on hypersonic in production?

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb, concept

Developers of [hypersonic](http://hsqldb.org/) promise increase of performance?

But I'm afraid problems with administrating and other aspects of using hsqlDB.

Are anybody using this in production? Is it good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Many companies](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlUsing.html) are using HSQL in production.

Among those not on the list, a certain well-known (though not necessarily well liked) company that makes an antivirus product (whose name rhymes with "Horton") is using HSQL-based software for their update server management. I know because I wrote it :-)

I'm not sure what "problems with administrating" you're referring to. They have both command-line and (somewhat simplistic) GUI clients plus pretty much everything is doable over JDBC so
you can take your pick from lots of tools / IDE plugins.

That said, whether using it is a good idea **for you** depends on your requirements. It's certainly not a drop-in replacement for Oracle (Postgres / DB2 / MySQL / what have you). But it most definitely has its uses.

Comment: problems with administrating - it was my error ) I see good tools.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to look at [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), which is a more full featured DB, while still supporting most of the features of HSQLDB like memory only DBs.